# Tabhost with 2 tabs and 2 listviews getting data from a database

Tags: android, listview, android-tabhost

I have followed several different tutorials without any luck on getting this to work. The only difference that I can see is that I am using a db to pull the data from and the tutorials a creating an array to get the data.

Here is the code I am working with to see if anyone can help me out.

main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>
        <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/listView2">
        </ListView>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

main.java file:

```
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabContentFactory;

import com.facebook.android.R;

public class MainLib extends TabActivity implements OnTabChangeListener {


private static final String TAG = "MainLib";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainlib);

    //final TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    //tabHost.setup();
    TabHost mTabHost = getTabHost();
    mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);

    // Find your views NEW LIBS
    final ListView listPro = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    final DBLibAdapter db = new DBLibAdapter(this);

    db.open();

    final Cursor c = db.getAllNewLibs();
    startManagingCursor(c);
    Log.d(TAG, "New Libs Cursor Created");

    // Create the adapter
    NewLibAdapter adapter = new NewLibAdapter(this, c);
    listPro.setAdapter(adapter);
    Log.d(TAG, "New Libs Adapter Created");

    db.close();


    listPro.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            db.open();

            db.updateId(id);

            db.close();

            Intent miamor = new Intent(MainLib.this, Result.class);
            startActivity(miamor);

        }
    });

    // Find your views SAVED LIBS
    final ListView listPro1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);

    db.open();

    final Cursor c1 = db.getAllSavedLibs();
        startManagingCursor(c1);

        Log.d(TAG, "Saved Libs Cursor Created");
    // Create the adapter
    SavedLibAdapter adapter1 = new SavedLibAdapter(this, c1);
    listPro1.setAdapter(adapter1);

    Log.d(TAG, "Saved Libs Adapter Created");

    db.close();

    listPro1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            db.open();

            db.updateId(id);

            db.close();

            Intent amormio = new Intent(MainLib.this, Result.class);
            startActivity(amormio);

        }
    });

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("New Libs").setIndicator("New Libs")
            .setContent(new TabContentFactory(){

                @Override
                public View createTabContent(String arg0) {
                    return listPro;
                }
            }));

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Saved Libs").setIndicator("Saved Libs")
            .setContent(new TabContentFactory(){

                @Override
                public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                    return listPro1;
                }
            }));

    mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
}

  public void onTabChanged(String tabName) {
      if(tabName.equals("New Libs")) {
          //do something
      }
      else if(tabName.equals("Saved Libs")) {
          //do something
      }
}
}
```

the first listView has data but the second on doesn't. I tried to remove the second one but it still throws an error message:

```
05-18 16:57:30.964: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32753): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
05-18 16:57:30.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32753): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-18 16:57:30.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32753):     at android.widget.TabHost.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(TabHost.java:295)
05-18 16:57:30.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32753):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:661)
05-18 16:57:30.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32753):     at android.widget.TabHost.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(TabHost.java:295)
05-18 16:57:30.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32753):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:661)
05-18 16:57:30.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32753):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:661)
05-18 16:57:30.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32753):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:661)
05-18 16:57:30.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32753):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1819)
05-18 16:57:30.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32753):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-18 16:57:30.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32753):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-18 16:57:30.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32753):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
05-18 16:57:30.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32753):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-18 16:57:30.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32753):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-18 16:57:30.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32753):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
05-18 16:57:30.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32753):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
05-18 16:57:30.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32753):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help!

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.mainlib) shouldn't this be setContentView(R.layout.main)?

Answer (score 0):

You are including the ListViews in the main layout. You need to create a layout for each activity instead. You are creating a layout on demand, but then referring to a listview in another layout (main).

See the Tab Layout tutorial: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html for an example.

Comment: You should manage each list inside a [ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) rather than a regular Activity